# how to add array in a single column in database table and also a new item in same array column in laravel 5.2(PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i am working on a project .in that project i have a subcategory table with id,catid,subcat,status columns.I have to add an array in a single column (subcat). now the problem is how to add a array in the single column of table . i have to add more item in that row where the array is stored in future ... like (insert into tablename ___________________ where id= $id)..

so plz tell me how to add a array in single column of table and update that array for further use. 
thankx 
regards

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest you that, but you can encode that array using for example json-encode, and store that string in that column. Drawback of this is that you can not update "items" of that array without retrivieng it from db and decoding it to php array. I would suggest you to look at MySQL 5.7 where that feature is supported. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Foreign key to achieve this. See the following table schema:

```
mysql> describe categories;
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| category_id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| category_name      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| sub_category_id    | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0                 |                |
| created_at         | timestamp   | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| updated_at         | timestamp   | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Here your `sub_category_id` references to `categories` table's `category_id`.
This will also allow you to have multiple levels in your sub-category.
Category Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Category extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
    protected $fillable = array(''category_name'sub_category_id');

    public function Sub_Category(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\category','sub_category_id','category_id');
    }

}
```